# Using sqlite out of a Context

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-context

I have a class that extends ArrayAdapter (adaptadorTemas, is an adapter for a listView).
I have another class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper (sqlStuff).

So, I'd like to make a query to the DB from my adapter class, but i got this error:
**The constructor SqlStuff(AdaptadorTemas, String, null, int) is undefined**

Eclipse made a constructor in my SQLiteOpenHelper class to fix the problem, but then i got this one:

**The constructor SQLiteOpenHelper(AdaptadorTemas, String, Object, int) is undefined**

I don't understand what's happening... any help, please?

Comment: could you please post some code..

Comment: post the code off SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions here:

1. You can add a field `private Context theContext;` to your custom ArrayAdapter subclass that can store a Context. Then you can pass an Activity instance or the Application Context to the constructor. From there, you can just call `SqlStuff(theContext, ...)` to create your SqlStuff class.
2. You could make your ArrayAdapter subclass a private inner class of the Activity that you are using it in, defined in the same java file as that Activity. Then, you can get an instance of the outer Activity class very easily to pass to SqlStuff just with `MyActivity.this`. I prefer this method in my applications.